# Monster Template Form - News Letter sign up?

Tags: html, forms, encoding, newsletter

I purchased a template from Template Monster and I can not get the newsletter or the feedback forms to work. I have contacted them and they won't help with this unless I pay them more money?!

Can anyone help me with this?

This is the code in the html website - Where do I put in my email address to send the information too?

```
<h2><b>Newsletter</b><span>sign up</span></h2>
    <form action="" id="form1">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="h1"> 
             <input type="text" class="input" value="Enter Your Name" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter Your Name'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Enter Your Name' ) this.value=''"  />
           </div>
           <div class="h2">
             <input type="text" class="input" value="Enter Your E-Mail" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter Your E-Mail'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Enter Your E-Mail' ) this.value=''"  /><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit()"><img alt="" src="images/button-1.gif" /></a>
           </div>
       </div>
  </form>
```

I tried to replacing "#" with my email address and "mailto:myemail.com" but nothing is working. There is no document for this form in the folder that I can see? There is different JS files but I tried to look through them to see if I can enter an email, but can't find anything.